# How would I go about making a stand alone app on my dock to open a game using a terminal command?

Tags: terminal, applescript, games, wine

I have a game that they never released for mac, and I installed the game using WINE, the install itself was flawless, but every time I want to play it, I'm forced to open Terminal and run

```
cd /Users/Max/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Electronic\ Arts/Dead\ Space/
wine Dead\ Space.exe
```

I saw a question that I thought would answer this using applescript, but when i tried to duplicate the example, it didn't work. I'm sure the information I've given is enough to start the answer to my problem, if not, just let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

create the following plain text file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/Max/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Electronic\ Arts/Dead\ Space/
exec wine Dead\ Space.exe
```

save it as dead_space.command

in Terminal, change it to an executabe:

```
sudo chmod +rx dead_space.command
```

Now, the file `dead_space.command` should start your game when you double click on it.

Comment: I'm not to experienced in using terminal, how would I go about changing it?

Comment: forgot to tag in my comment

Comment: My bad i went and looked it up and found it I didn't realize you had it posted right there.. Thanks a bunch... While I've got you here is there anyway I can change that Icon to a different one on the executable?

Comment: Yes you can change the icon! 

Open your icon/image with preview. Select all: [CMD] + [A]

Copy: [CMD] + [C]

Select your freshly created command file in finder and press [CMD] + [i]

Now select the icon in the left top corner of the info pane and press paste: [CMD] + [v]

That's it!

Comment: I actually figured that one out moments ago... but one thing I cant seem to figure out is how to get it on the dock... I can put it near my downloads stack and trash, but I want it to look like an application icon, you know... like it would belong with my other games like wow/diablo, ect. Another question I'd like to ask along with that is if there is a way to make a stack with a changed icon specifically for games... like you know downloads, but with all my game.app files as well as my homeade executables... Thanks for the info, btw!

Comment: You can create a folder with a custom icon the same way you can change the icon of the shell command (see my previous comment).

Comment: Alrighty, is there anyway to force this folder into the Applications side of my dock? and still have the functionality of a stack?

Comment: You can create an 'app' from an executable using appify. Appify is wrapper for shell scripts that makes them look and work like 'apps': https://sixohthree.com/1314/shell-scripts-as-applications-in-mac-os-x

Comment: I don't think you can put the folder into the applications side of the dock, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Well, I suppose that I'll ask in another post about the stacks that work in the applications side of docks, thanks for all your help, the appify thing is EXACTLY what i couldnt find anywhere on google (must've been my wording). Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Lol, I just made that icon, then made the stack and realized it was redundant to have it on the desktop and dock so i deleted the desktop one... and now im starting all over... round 2!

Comment: I've got a new Problem, When I put the executable in my new stack, it shows the shell document icon, but if its by itself right next to the folder, it will show it...

Comment: I ended up changing the extension to .app, when I did this, the executable no longer worked, but it showed the icon in the stack, so I changed it back, and it never removed the icon, so now its perfect.

Comment: The previous comment applies for putting files that arent applications in the applications side of the dock as well.

Comment: I got the appify author to fix their dead link. I also backed up appify.sh to a permanent URL https://gist.github.com/air/a0d495966288303dd202

Answer (score 5):

This is perhaps "heavier" than Vincent's solution, but you can create a new Automator document and set type as Application.

In the Actions, search for "shell" and drag "Run Shell Script" over to the workflow on the right. Then just enter your commands. Save it and it will be an OS X application that you can put on your Dock like any other.

This might be easier to edit later, and it's good to be familiar with Automator and what it can do :D

[image: Automator document]

Comment: This one worked for making Notepad++ as an app without opening ugly terminal window

Answer (score 0):

If you use Automator like @iynque said, you'll end up with an .app
Then you can **change the icon** on the .app you created by creating an icns file here: https://iconverticons.com/online/  (just drag & drop).

Then right-click your app, do "Get Info" and on the info window, drag and drop your icns file onto the existing icon for the app.

Here is an example of an automator script that resets my DNS, used my horse as an icon 8-P.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*WineBottler* app](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) which can create Windows-based programs as macOS apps.

It also comes with *Wine.app*, so you can just choose executable files to be opened by *Wine* without typing the commands in *Terminal* each time.

Another way is to install *Wine.app* via Brew Cask, e.g. `brew cask install wine-stable`.